# Last MotionEvent with strange coordinates

Tags: android, android-ndk

We have puzzle game Fruit Dating that is some time already out. Now we got report from one of our players that he can not touch any item in menu. We sent him special version with onscreen debugging. We focused on touches and he returned us this result:

[image: touch events]
 There is every touch event intercepted. I split set of touch events for every single "game touch" in the picure with red lines on the left. Every game touch event is like this: down - (one or more drag) - up. What is strange is that before there is touch up there is always big jump in touch coordinates with touch dragged event.

I think that most of the drag events is just bouncing but there is always at least one that jumps coordinates to lower left corner. Following up event is then with these incorrect coordinates. As we are checking whether the player is touching up in the same area (see area parameter) as he began when touching down then there is never any match and player has feeling that the game is stuck.

The player that reported error has THL W200 phone. We previously tested on lot of different physical devices but never encountered this problem...

Does anyone have some idea why there is motion event (drag) with such a strange coordinates? Did any of you encountered it?

Our game is JNI with thin Java layer. Motionevents are sent to c++ from view like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent aEvent) 
{
    final int action = aEvent.getAction();

    queueEvent(new Runnable()
    {
        int motionEvent = -1;

        public void run()
        {
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                motionEvent = ANDROID_TOUCH_ACTION_DOWN;
            }
            else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                motionEvent = ANDROID_TOUCH_ACTION_UP;
            }
            else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                motionEvent = ANDROID_TOUCH_ACTION_MOVE;
            }

            SBCEngine.engine_on_touch((int) aEvent.getX(), (int) aEvent.getY(), motionEvent);
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution, so if anyone is interested...

The above code is not safe. Before the event is processed the referenced event object may change. The code was taken from book on porting Doom and Quake to Android and you may found similar code at web. It worked on all tested devices until yesterday. It failed on THL W200 device.

I changed the code to this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent aEvent) 
{
    // get masked (not specific to a pointer) action
    int maskedAction = aEvent.getActionMasked();

    switch (maskedAction)
    {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
    {
        // get pointer index from the event object
        int pointerIndex = aEvent.getActionIndex();
        // get pointer ID
        int pointerId = aEvent.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

        //Log.d("POINTER", "pointer down: ID = " + pointerId + " x=" + aEvent.getX(pointerIndex) + ", y = " + aEvent.getY(pointerIndex));
        queueEvent(new MotionEventRunnable(pointerId, maskedAction,
                        (int) aEvent.getX(pointerIndex),
                        (int) aEvent.getY(pointerIndex)));
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    { 
        // a pointer was moved
        int size = aEvent.getPointerCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            // Get the pointer ID and index
            int pointerId = aEvent.getPointerId(i);
            int pointerIndex = aEvent.findPointerIndex(pointerId);

            //Log.d("POINTER", "pointer move: ID = " + pointerId + " x=" + aEvent.getX(pointerIndex) + ", y = " + aEvent.getY(pointerIndex));
            queueEvent(new MotionEventRunnable(pointerId, maskedAction,
                    (int) aEvent.getX(pointerIndex),
                    (int) aEvent.getY(pointerIndex)));
        }
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    {
        // get pointer index from the event object
        int pointerIndex = aEvent.getActionIndex();
        // get pointer ID
        int pointerId = aEvent.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

        //Log.d("POINTER", "pointer up: ID = " + pointerId + " x=" + aEvent.getX(pointerIndex) + ", y = " + aEvent.getY(pointerIndex));
        queueEvent(new MotionEventRunnable(pointerId, maskedAction,
                (int) aEvent.getX(pointerIndex),
                (int) aEvent.getY(pointerIndex)));
        break;
    }
    }

    return true;
}
```

with MotionEventRunnable class like this:

```
class MotionEventRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private int mPointerID;
    private int mActionID;
    private int mX, mY;

  //-----------------------------------------------------
    public MotionEventRunnable(int aPointerID, int aActionID, int aX, int aY)
    {
        mPointerID = aPointerID;
        mActionID = aActionID;
        mX = aX;
        mY = aY;
    }

  //-----------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // send to native
        SBCEngine.engine_on_touch(mPointerID, mX, mY, mActionID);
    }
}
```

The code is more complex as it also handles multitouch but the point is that I cache all the required values: pointer id, action, x and y. It solved my problems.